# Koa.js: Centralized error handling

Tags: node.js, mongoose, error-handling, koa, koa2

I'm using Koa.js and MongoDB via Mongoose. I'm want to know how to implement a perfect centralized error handling mechanism.

For instance, there is some issue in the function that I've written to connect to  MongoDB via Mongoose. Which is why I'm getting the following error. However, I want to capture this error and handle it in a centralized fashion. Meaning, I want all the errors and warning (no matter from which part of the application) to be handled by a function in my application which will log it.

```
warning.js:18 (node:11776) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [127.0.0.1:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: read ECONNRESET]
    writeOut @ warning.js:18
    output @ warning.js:69
    process.on @ warning.js:100
    emitOne @ events.js:116
    emit @ events.js:211
    (anonymous) @ warning.js:74
    _combinedTickCallback @ next_tick.js:131
    _tickCallback @ next_tick.js:180
    TickObject (async)
    init @ inspector_async_hook.js:22
    emitInitNative @ async_hooks.js:472
    emitInitScript @ async_hooks.js:388
    nextTick @ next_tick.js:270
    process.emitWarning @ warning.js:146
    emitWarning @ promises.js:75
    emitPendingUnhandledRejections @ promises.js:95
    _tickCallback @ next_tick.js:189
    Show 11 more blackboxed frames

warning.js:18 (node:11776) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
    writeOut @ warning.js:18
    output @ warning.js:69
    process.on @ warning.js:100
    emitOne @ events.js:116
    emit @ events.js:211
    (anonymous) @ warning.js:74
    _combinedTickCallback @ next_tick.js:131
    _tickCallback @ next_tick.js:180
    TickObject (async)
    init @ inspector_async_hook.js:22
    emitInitNative @ async_hooks.js:472
    emitInitScript @ async_hooks.js:388
    nextTick @ next_tick.js:270
    process.emitWarning @ warning.js:146
    emitWarning @ promises.js:78
    emitPendingUnhandledRejections @ promises.js:95
    _tickCallback @ next_tick.js:189
    Show 11 more blackboxed frames

warning.js:18 (node:11776) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [127.0.0.1:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: read ECONNRESET]
    writeOut @ warning.js:18
    output @ warning.js:69
    process.on @ warning.js:100
    emitOne @ events.js:116
    emit @ events.js:211
    (anonymous) @ warning.js:74
    _combinedTickCallback @ next_tick.js:131
    _tickCallback @ next_tick.js:180
    TickObject (async)
    init @ inspector_async_hook.js:22
    emitInitNative @ async_hooks.js:472
    emitInitScript @ async_hooks.js:388
    nextTick @ next_tick.js:270
    process.emitWarning @ warning.js:146
    emitWarning @ promises.js:75
    emitPendingUnhandledRejections @ promises.js:95
    _tickCallback @ next_tick.js:189
    Show 11 more blackboxed frames
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a section on error handling in the Koa wiki: https://github.com/koajs/koa/wiki/Error-Handling

They recommend using an error handler middleware as one of the first middlewares in your application so that any errors thrown downstream will bubble up to it.

Their example from the wiki:

```
app.use(async (ctx, next) => {
  try {
    await next();
  } catch (err) {
    ctx.status = err.status || 500;
    ctx.body = err.message;
    ctx.app.emit('error', err, ctx);
  }
});

app.on('error', (err, ctx) => {
  /* centralized error handling:
   *   console.log error
   *   write error to log file
   *   save error and request information to database if ctx.request match condition
   *   ...
  */
});
```

Comment: But this does not catch any error, lets say when the server is initialised or just starting, etc. basically before this `app.use` function.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will ensure that any unhandled promise error or any uncaught error, if not handled locally, will get its treatment:

```js
app.use(async (ctx, next) => {
  try {
    await next();
  } catch (err) {
    ctx.status = err.status || 500;
    ctx.body = err.message;
    ctx.app.emit('error', err, ctx);
  }
});

...

someUnhandledError();

...


process.on("unhandledRejection", (reason: string) => {
  // I just caught an unhandled promise rejection,
  // let's throw it here so my central error handler can catch it
  throw new AppError(reason, 500);
});

process.on('uncaughtException', (error: Error) => {
  // I just received an error that was never handled, time to handle it
  // by throwing it so my error handling middleware can catch it
  throw new AppError("Error", 500)
});

app.on('error', (err, ctx) => {
  // centralized error handling:
  // console.log(error)
  // write error to log file
});

app.listen(3000);
```

*Note: Here, the `AppError` class being used is a custom class that extends the `Error` class.*